# Do I have to define attributes in the base class in python?

Tags: python

This is kind of a "best practices" question, but my IDE is throwing a warning at me when I commit my code, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

"Unresolved attribute reference "attribute" for class "BaseClass".

Essentially I have a base class, with get and set methods.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        foo = obj.bar
        foo.findmethod(self.attribute).setmethod(value)
```

Then, I inherit from this class when using actual classes I will use:

```
class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    attribute = this

class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    attribute = that
```

As I will never use the base class directly, I don't see a reason to define this attribute at that level.  But the warning makes me wonder if this is bad practice.  Apologies if my naming convention is confusing.

Comment: Why not just ignore the IDE warning? Python doesn't care.

Comment: That's why I don't use IDEs for Python. I hate pointless warnings.

Comment: You can certainly ignore it, but simply adding `attribute = None` to the `BaseClass` makes it go away with little fuss. The downside is that any sub-classes where you *forget* to define `attribute` now run for a little longer before getting to a place where something doesn't work and it spits out an error to tell you!

Comment: IDEs for python are extremely useful. However, you have to understand that not everything they say is a real problem. Anyway, I would define ``attribute`` in the base class as abstract (using ``abc``, defining a property and rasing ``NotImplementedError`` or even with an attribute descriptor). The IDE does not complain, and you make clear that customers of your code must implement it.

Comment: jonrsharpe - that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, doing something that makes failure cases more confusing in the future.  For now I did add `attribute = None`, we'll see how it goes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I guess I didn't make it abundantly clear in the question that I knew I could ignore the IDE warning.  I'm operating under the assumption that whoever wrote the IDE has more programming experience than me, so I want to know why they're throwing a warning before I just blindly ignore it.

Comment: @DanRobson: IDEs have to make educated guesses here and use fixed rules. Like all computer programs, these warnings are applied rigorously like a robot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @jonrsharpe, but not only in the way of workaround, but as a general practice. I think it serves very well to self-documentation and code readability to define the attributes that you set in initializer or elsewhere in instance life, at class-level. Even better if you document them.

```
class BaseClass(object):

    attribute = None
    '''Should be defined in a subclass. Use for something, here and there.'''


    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        foo = obj.bar
        foo.findmethod(self.attribute).setmethod(value)
```

Comment: Comments are for those who can't code clean. Define a ``property`` that raises a ``NotImplementedError``. If you ever hit the condition, you will get something better than ``NoneType has no attr...`` or equivalent.

Comment: @ikaros45 partially I can agree with you. Writing a comment just to write a comment makes no sense. Meaningful names and intuitive behaviour are preferred. But comments are also for those how deal with complex things and like anyone need to make assumptions. Also for Sphinx.   Taking specifically about the inheritance contract here, I don't agree that writing a property that will raise `NonImplementedError` is anything good. It'll be pointless overengineering, because you don't inherit from unknown. It's a deliberate decision, which leads to figuring out the contract.

Comment: Thanks guys, I can see both sides of this argument.  On one hand, it would be nice to have something a little more descriptive if I were to use this class improperly.  On the other hand, I can't spend all my time coding around failure conditions.  I'll find a balance.  Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: I don't agree it is overengineering, in fact it is simpler than the solution the module ``abc`` offers. I agree it is verbose. This is why I normally use a descriptor to handle these cases, and when defining the "contract" I just type ``attribute = NotImplementedAttribute()``.

Comment: @ikaros45 I see your point. But I hope you don't forget Python's *we're all consenting adults here* attitude. You may have perfectly functional and maintainable code without classical OO nomenclature like interfaces, abstract classes, etc. It is usually enough to keep the code semantically correct with these concepts if you mean them. There's also no problem with externalizing them in code, if that makes you feel safer. Like OP told, it's about finding balance.

Comment: Well, I can't disagree :)

Comment: What if BaseClass is from an imported module? It does not make sense and is not possible to include all attributes in the BaseClass.